# How to upgrade Xcode to 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

On my mac I have macOS version 10.12.6 and Xcode 9.1 installed on it.

I want to download Xcode 9.2 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

My question is should I first uninstall Xcode that I have installed before downloading Xcode 9.2 or not ? Is this the full version of Xcode or just the upgrade ?

Comment: If you do a manual download and installation, you will retain both your Xcodes (9.1 and 9.2). So delete the previous copy before installation if you don't want both. If you download it via AppStore (Given that your previous version was also downloaded from from AppStore), it will update your existing 9.1 to 9.2.

Comment: Okay then I will download Xcode 9.2 from this link and I should be fine. I just bought iPhone 8 Plus and it is not compatible with Xcode 9.1 but it needs Xcode 9.2

Comment: @IOSdeveloper I strongly suggest you to download Xcode 9.3, as it fixes some bugs of 9.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode version from your link (Apple Developer Portal) is the full version of Xcode. If you download `Xcode 9.2` from here, you will still have `9.1` version installed, and would be able to use both.

It can be useful to keep several versions of `Xcode`, as some comes with bugs, but every `Xcode` instance takes about 10GB.

The only way to "update" `Xcode` is with `App Store`, by clicking `Update` button, but it only works if the previously installed version was downloaded with the `App Store`.

As a side note, **I strongly advise you** to download `9.3` version, as it fixes some of `9.2` bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will get Xcode 9.2 from this link and keep both versions.

Comment: @IOSdeveloper Please see my edit, you should download 9.3

Comment: Thanks again you are very helpful I will download 9.3

Comment: You're welcome buddy :)

Comment: I got so excited when i finally downloaded Xcode 9.3 but forgot i need to upgrade my macOS to high Sierra as well so I will download Xcode 9.2 even though it has bugs just so I can avoid downloading high sierra.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to inform you about this. Okay for 9.2, the major bug concerns iOS 8, do you plan iOS 8 support ?

Comment: No I don't only for IOS 10 and later. Still thank you for your time

Comment: Ok so you won’t have any annoying problem with 9.2. Happy coding ;)

Comment: I can't believe i still get the same error with xcode 9.2 - This iPhone 8 Plus (Model A1864, A1897, A1898, A1899) is running iOS 11.2.5 (15D60), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

Comment: Xcode should be able to run iOS 11.2 by default. Please check your installed SDK (in Xcode Settings)